# Movement Speed in pygame

Tags: python, pygame, pycharm

I am working on a project in Pygame that I am having minor trouble with. I have coded the entirety of the game, and it runs perfectly, but I would like my character to slow movement when walking over certain terrain. For example, if he/she walks over a sand tile than I would like for his/her speed to cut in half. I have not been able to figure this out on my own as I am still learning. The link to my code is below. Any help would be much appreciated!

I believe the solution will come within these lines of code:

```
if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        is_facing_left = True
        movement_x -= tile_rect.width
        mapx -= 1
    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        is_facing_left = False
        movement_x += tile_rect.width
        mapx += 1
    if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
        movement_y -= tile_rect.height
        mapy -= 1
    if keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
        movement_y += tile_rect.height
        mapy += 1

    if mapx < 0:
        mapx = 0
        movement_x = 0
    if mapx > world.get_width()-1 - map_tile_width:
        mapx = world.get_width()-1 - map_tile_width
        movement_x = 0
    if mapy < 0:
        mapy = 0
        movement_y = 0
    if mapy > world.get_height()-1 - map_tile_height:
        mapy = world.get_height()-1 - map_tile_height
        movement_y = 0
```

The full code is here:

https://github.com/DanPatWils/AdventureGame/blob/master/Almost

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! Could you please reduce your code to a minimal, complete and verifiable ([mcve](www.stackoverflow.com/mcve)) example? In this way you'll easily get help! Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, toti08! Just edited the question! I appreciate your response, as I am new here!

Answer (score 0):

You can multiply the base speed of the player by a number depending on the terrain they are on. When walking on normal tiles, this number could be set to 1, which means no change in speed, or set to 0.5 which would cut speed in half.

From what I can understand from the code, it looks like you are moving one pixel at a time. You could multiply this by 0.5 to make the player move at half the speed.

If you could provide a minimal runnable example or put more comments in your code, you are likely to receive a better answer.